Where does the serial number request by fastboot come from?
fastboot uses a serial number to identify devices and this serial number is sometimes used by bootloader unlock services. Where is this serial number stored on the phone?

I assume your actual question is not only where the serial number is stored but if/how the serial number can be changed, correct?

unrelated but similar question Change adb device name
